# Prove there is a neighborhood around $0$ such that $f$ is bi-Lipschiz

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n$ be $C^1$ and $D_f(0)=I$. Prove there is a neighborhood around 0 where $B||x-y||\le||f(x)-f(y)||\le A||x-y||$ for $A,B>0$. What I did so far is: $f(x)=Ix+o(|x|)=x+o(|x|)$. Therefore: $||f(x)-f(y)||=||x-y+o(|x|)-o(|y|)||$ and this is where I am stuck a little. Maybe arriving at $||f(x)-f(y)||\le ||x-y||+o(||x||)+o(||y||)$. I can't think of any guiding concept nor can I see how things change getting closer to the origin. Maybe I am after a pair of points with the maximal difference $||f(x)-f(y)||-||x-y||$? I could really use your help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $f$ is supposed to be $\mathcal{C}^1$ and $D_f(0)=I$, one can find a neighborhood of the origin $V$ such that for $x \in V$: $\Vert D_f(x) \Vert \le B=\frac{3}{2}$. Using the [Mean Value Theorem in several variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables), you get $$\Vert f(x)-f(y) \Vert \le B \Vert x-y \Vert$$ for $x,y \in V$.

The other inequality is obtains using the [Inverse function theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem). Because $f$ is supposed to be $\mathcal{C}^1$ and $D_f(0)=I$, one can find a neighborhood $W$ such that $f$ is invertible in $W$. You then get the first inequality applying above paragraph to $f^{-1}$.